# What is the difference between $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ and $SL(3, \mathbb R)$?

Tags: projective-geometry, linear-groups, general-linear-group

Every element $\alpha$ in $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ is represented by a matrix $A \in GL(3, \mathbb R)$; two such matrices $A_1, A_2 \in GL(3, \mathbb R)$ represent the same element $\alpha$ if and only if $A_1 = kA_2$ for some nonzero $k \in \mathbb R$.

It seems to me that for each $A \in GL(3, \mathbb R)$, we can choose $k = \frac{1}{(\det A)^{1/3}}$, so that $\det (kA) = 1$, and therefore $kA \in SL(3, \mathbb R)$.  Therefore there is a "natural" isomorphism between $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ and $SL(3, \mathbb R)$.

Is there any reason *not* to identify $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ with $SL(3, \mathbb R)$? Is there a sense in which this identification obscures some important distinctions we should care about?

Comment: Typos in what you've written?: $PGL(2,k)$ is not the quotient of $GL(3,k)$ by its center...  $PGL(n,k)$ is the quotient of $GL(n,k)$ by its center, for any field $k$. But/and, yes, $SL(n,k)$ is "close" to being $PGL(n,k)$, but off by roots of unity. Sometimes this doesn't matter, but sometimes it does.

Comment: @paulgarrett Is it possible that there is more than one convention regarding what $PGL(n, k)$ means? I am using Hartshorne, *Foundations of Projective Geometry*, in which $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ denotes the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{RP}^2$: "Hence an element of $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ is represented by a $3\times 3$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ of real numbers, with $\det A \ne 0$, and two matrices $A, A'$ represent the same element of the group if and only if there is a real number $\lambda\ne 0$ such that $A' = \lambda A$." (p. 37)....

Comment: (contd)  ...This seems to say that $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ is a quotient of $GL(3, \mathbb R)$, in much the same way that $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a quotient of $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Also my question was not about $PGL(n, k)$ generally, but about $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ specifically, in which context the salient piece of information is that every nonzero real number has exactly one cube root, so the "off by roots of unity" issue seems irrelevant...

Comment: I guess it's conceivable that there is more than one convention about this indexing, but, honestly, I've been fooling around with GL(n) and PGL(n) and... for 50 years, and have never seen the convention you mention. (I would have assumed it was a typo, possibly!) :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Interesting.  Maybe worth posting as a separate question...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202585/do-different-naming-conventions-exist-regarding-what-pgln-k-means