# Do different naming conventions exist regarding what $PGL(n, k)$ means?

Tags: projective-geometry, linear-groups, general-linear-group

According to Hartshorne, *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*, $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ denotes the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{RP}^2$, the real projective plane, and is therefore a quotient of $GL(3, \mathbb R)$.  That is, there appears to be an off-by-one convention in the use of the numerical index; in this sense the convention is similar to the fact that $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is a quotient of $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$.

Hartshorne writes explicitly:

> Hence an element of $PGL(2, \mathbb R)$ is represented by a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ of real numbers, with $\det A  \ne 0$, and two matrices $A, A'$ represent the same element of the group if and only if there is a real number $\lambda \ne 0$ such that $A' = \lambda A$.

But the general consensus (as evidenced by [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group) and by the [comments on another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201819/what-is-the-difference-between-pgl2-mathbb-r-and-sl3-mathbb-r?noredirect=1#comment8718377_4201819)) seems to be that $PGL(n, k)$ is a quotient of $GL(n, k)$, not a quotient of $GL(n+1, k)$.  That is, the index $n$ in $PGL(n, k)$ designates the index of the parent space of which it is a quotient, not the dimension of the projective space on which it acts.

Are both conventions widely used, but in different contexts?  (For example, perhaps algebraic geometers use one convention, and group theorists use the other?)  Is one perhaps more archaic?  (I note that Hartshorne's book is 54 years old; perhaps it reflects an older convention?)  Is there a consensus, nowadays, on which of these is "right"?

Or is it possible that I am misunderstanding something, and that in fact there is no disagreement here at all?

**Edited to add:**  I just checked Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* to see if he uses the same convention in that other, better-known book, and can confirm that he does:

p. 151:

> **Example 7.1.1** (Automorphisms of $\mathbf{P}^n_k$). If $\|a_{ij}\|$ is an invertible $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix of elements of a field $k$, then $x_i' = \sum a_{ij}x_j$ determines an automorphism of the polynomial ring $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ and hence also an automorphism of $\mathbf{P}^n_k$. If $\lambda \in k$ is a nonzero element, then $\| \lambda a_{ij} \|$ determines the same automorphism of $\mathbf{P}^n_k$. So we are led to consider the group $PGL(n, k) = GL(n+1, k)/k^*$, which acts as a group of automorphisms of $\mathbf{P}^n_k$.

So at least Hartshorne is self-consistent in this regard.

Comment: For whatever its worth, I have never seen the convention as quoted in Hartshorne.  I would have said that the other convention was universal.

Comment: Side note:  As I studied Algebraic Geometry out of Hartshorne's text when it was brand new, I find it distressing to see it referred to as old.  Sigh.

Comment: I might echo here my comments on the question that generated this question... That is, with the shift in index, I had assumed that that original question had a typo, namely, that "of course" $PGL(n,k)$ is the quotient of $GL(n,k)$ by its center (for any commutative ring $k$ with identity, at least). I have spent more than 50 years  involved with classical groups, etc., and had not seen the convention quoted from Hartshorne's book until just today.

Comment: As a newcomer to this, I have to say that it does seem natural to match the index to the dimension of the projective space on which the group of automorphisms acts, and I am rather surprised that Hartshorne’s convention is **not** the standard one.

Comment: @lulu see my latest edit...